PowerPivot to find specific text
I need to find specific text in a column in PowerPivot but the field is sometimes spelt incorrectly.
EG:



Data
Open/Closed




(Cloosed) Emp 1



Emp 2



(Account Closeeed) Emp 3



(CLOSED) Emp 4



(Closeed) Emp 5



Emp 6 (CLD FO)




The only consistent thing i can use is:
Look within the first set of brackets
Must have
"(*cl*ed)"
I have used this :
=IF(SEARCH("(*cl*ed)", _EmpData[DATA], 1, 0) >0,"CLOSED","OPEN")
I need to change this to only look in the first set of brackets as you can see from the above example table some data has a second set of brackets in which is being picked up when it shouldnt
Can someone advise on how to only search if the first character in the cell is a ( please?

Create a calculated column :
Your Column = IF(
    LEFT(_EmpData[DATA], 1) = "(",
    IF(
        SEARCH("*cl*ed", 
            LEFT(
                MID(_EmpData[DATA], 2, FIND(")", _EmpData[DATA]) - 2),
                FIND(")", _EmpData[DATA]) - 2
            )
        ) > 0,
        "CLOSED",
        "OPEN"
    ),
    "OPEN"
)


You need to evaluate each row so the LEFT(_EmpData[DATA], 1) extracts the first character of the text in the  column, if it is "(" go to the next row.
I used MID to start extracting  from the 2nd character just after the opening bracket and the FIND(")", _EmpData[DATA]) will locate the position of the first ")".
Here the number of characters to extract is calculated as the position of the closing bracket minus 2 (I exclude both the opening bracket and the starting position).
Then I search for the the pattern "cled" within the text I extracted from the 1set set of brackets, if it is found SEARCH returns a number greater 0 where "CLOSED" otherwise "OPEN".

As much as I can understand your question, I can provide you with this formula:
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("(*cl*ed)",A2:A7,1)=1,"CLOSED","OPEN"),"OPEN")


